# Use grunt-usemin to replace ref in my assets files(css, js) with CDN file

Tags: cdn, grunt-usemin

I use grunt build project, now i want to put the images and some static js files to cloud storage;

I know `grunt-usemin` can do this, but document is too too little and no examples;

Someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately usemin doesn't do that which is a shame, try this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cdnify